# Show that sequences in $\ell^1$ containing finite number of non-zero elements are dense in $\ell^1$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Take sequences from $\ell^1$ which have a finite number of elements other than $0$. Prove, that these sequences are dense in $\ell^1$. What does it imply?

I  tried to use the definition of densitiy such that

A is dense in $\ell^1$, if
$$ \forall x\in \ell^1 ,\quad \forall\epsilon>0,\quad \exists a\in A:\quad  d(x,a)<\epsilon$$
Unfortunately I fail to see how this proves the initial assumption.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: If you have $x = (x^1,x^2,x^3, \dots) \in \ell^1$, what's the distance of $x_n := (x^1, x^2, \dots, x^n, 0, \dots)$ and $x$?

Comment: That means that $d(x,x_n)<\epsilon \qquad \forall \epsilon >0$?

Comment: No, not for all $\epsilon > 0$. But for a given $\epsilon$, you might be able to make that distance smaller than that $\epsilon$. How?

Comment: I'm having a hard time grasping the meaning of distance in the context of sequences. Does it mean a sum of pairwise distance e.g. $\sum_k^\infty{|x_{n_k}-x_k|}$, or maybe the number of elements they differ in?

Comment: That's exactly the defintion of the distance (for the case of $\|\cdot\|_1$)! $d(x,y)=\|x-y\_1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x^n - y^n|$. (The indices are always a bit cumbersome when you work with sequences of sequences. I'd step away from a notation like $x_{n_k}$ unless you mean a sub-sequence of $x_n$, such as $x_1,x_2,x_4,x_8$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, but deviating in notation:

$\ell^1$, the space of all summable sequences has the norm $$\|x\|_1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_n,$$

where $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is a sequence. Hence, the induced metric is given by $$d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_1= \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_n - y_n|,$$

i.e. the series of the sum of absolute values of the componentwise difference of $x$ and $y$ (you can think of $x$ as a row vector with an infinite number of rows and the additional property that the absolute values of the row entries are summable).

If you want to have $y$ close to $x$, then their difference needs to be a series whose entries sum to a small number.

To get back to your question: How do we approximate any given $x \in \ell^1$ with elements from $A$, the space of sequences which are eventually zero?

For a given $x= (x_1,x_2, x_3, \dots)$, we can 'truncate' $x$ at the point $k$, i.e. we let

$$x^{(k)}=(x_1,x_2, x_3,\dots,x_k, 0,0,\dots)$$

so that up to the $k-$element, the sequence $x^{(k)}$ coincides with $x$ and beyond the $k-$th element, it's equal to zero.

1. What's the value of $d(x,x^{(k)})$?
2. Why does this value decrease as $k$ increases?

Answer (score 2):

For $a=(a_n )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \ell_1$ and $q_n (a) =(a_k)_{k=1}^n $ we have $$d(q_n (a) ,a) =\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} |a_j | \to 0$$ as $n\to\infty .$